# javascript redirection only on second try

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a little "webpage" to start streams on my xbmc with jsonrpc. Now the problem I am facing is that i always have to send the form request twice to make it work. could it be that I am using the window.open function wrong? or am I missing something?

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function postFunction() { // inside script tags
var vForm = document.getElementById("frmGui");
var vStrServer = "";
var vStrFile = "";
var vStrPost = "http://";

vStrServer = vForm.idServer.value;
vStrFile = vForm.idFile.value;
vStrPost += vStrServer+"/jsonrpc?request={\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\", ";
vStrPost += "\"id\":0, \"method\": \"Player.Open\", \"params\":{\"item\""
vStrPost += ":{\"file\":\""+vStrFile+"\"}}}";
window.open(vStrPost,"_self");
 }
</script>
</head>
<table>
<tr>
<form id="frmGui" name="gui" action="#" onSubmit="postFunction(this)" methode="POST">
<td><input id="idServer" name="server" type="text" value="IP_ADRESS"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="idFile" name="file" type="text"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit"/></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe it's a typo in your example, but `methode="POST"` should be `method="POST"`

Comment: @Bartdude I corected it but it wasn't the source of the behavior

Answer (score 1):

Try to put it into window.onload(cb).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload

Answer (score 0):

Why you passed argument whene you call `postFunction()` ? it has not argument upon decliration right way is

```
<form id="frmGui" name="gui" action="#" onSubmit="postFunction()" methode="POST">
```

remove this inside `postFunction` brace

Comment: still doesn't change anything